# Use a progressbar defined in another activity

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I found a progressbar (indeterminate) that I would use in my little app. 
This progressbar it´s in an activity, this is the progressbar:

https://gist.github.com/castorflex/4e46a9dc2c3a4245a28e

The problem is that I do not know how to call it from the activity where i want to show it.

Any idea?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I understand your question, but we will see.
Since you want to use the Drawable source code you have provided, then you would put the ProgressBar inside your XML layout as you normally would.
Then you would create an instance of your drawable in your activity.

```
SmoothCircularIndeterminateProgressDrawable progressDrawable = new SmoothCircularIndeterminateProgressDrawable(Color.BLUE, 1.0f);
```

Then you would simply call the [setIndeterminantDrawable(progressDrawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminateDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Comment: @MiguelC If you do not want to use it in a ProgressBar but in a custom view, I've added a sample class in the gist.